# iOS: AFNetworking: repeat a block if token expired

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c-blocks, token, afnetworking

I am writing a social networking app, where users will be able to follow other users and their activities.

On the server side, each user is identified with a **token** that expires after 60 minutes.

If the token has expired, and a user wants to call the method `- (void) followUserWithID:(NSNumber *)targetUserID` I would for this method to first call my **autologinMethod**(to ensure that the user's token is now valid) and then repeat `- (void) followUserWithID:(NSNumber *)targetUserID`

**Note**: I do not want to have a "checkValidToken" request that initiates an additional HTTP request.

```
-(void)commandWithParams:(NSMutableDictionary*)params command:(NSString *)command onCompletion:(JSONResponseBlock)completionBlock
{

    NSString *_path = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@%@",self.baseURL, command];
    NSLog(@"path: %@", _path );

    NSMutableURLRequest *apiRequest =
    [self multipartFormRequestWithMethod:@"POST"
                                    path:_path
                              parameters:params
               constructingBodyWithBlock: ^(id <AFMultipartFormData>formData) {
                   //TODO: attach file if needed
               }];


    AFJSONRequestOperation* operation = [[AFJSONRequestOperation alloc] initWithRequest: apiRequest];
    [operation setCompletionBlockWithSuccess:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, id responseObject) {
        //success!
        NSLog(@"%@",responseObject);

        completionBlock(responseObject);
    } failure:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, NSError *error) {
        //failure :(
        completionBlock([NSDictionary dictionaryWithObject:[error localizedDescription] forKey:@"ERROR"]);
        // Unable to establish a connection to the server.
        UIAlertView *alert = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Server error"
                                                        message:@"Please try again later"
                                                       delegate:nil
                                              cancelButtonTitle:@"OK"
                                              otherButtonTitles:nil];
        [alert show];
    }];

    [operation start];
}



- (void)followUserWithID:(NSNumber *)targetUserID
{
    NSNumber *ownID = [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] objectForKey:@"id"];
    NSMutableDictionary *HTTPPostDictionary = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc] initWithObjectsAndKeys:
                                               ownID, @"target_user_id",
                                               targetUserID, @"user_id",nil];

    [[WebAPI sharedInstance] commandWithParams:HTTPPostDictionary command:@"follow_user" onCompletion:^(NSDictionary *json){
        NSLog(@"%@", json);
    }];
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You need to

1. check whether the token is valid in the AFNetworking completion block
2. if the token has expired, renew it, and then retry the operation

Depending on the HTTP status code your server provides in this case, your check will either be in the `success` or `failure` block.

Here's a rough outline:

```
if (/* the token has expired */) {
    AFHTTPRequestOperation *operationToRetryAfterTokenRenewal = [operation copy];

    //TODO: set the completion blocks for operationToRetryAfterTokenRenewal.

    [myTokenRenewer autologinMethodWithCompletionBlock:^{
                     [operationToRetryAfterTokenRenewal start];
                 }];


}
```

Two notes:

1. Note the TODO.  When you copy an `AFHTTPRequestOperation` object, the completion blocks do not persist, so you need to set them again.  (See [AFURLConnectionOperation NSCopying Caveats](https://github.com/AFNetworking/AFNetworking/blob/master/AFNetworking/AFURLConnectionOperation.h#L87) for more info.)
2. You should really be using `[[myHTTPClient sharedClient] enqueueHTTPRequestOperation:operation]` instead of `[operation start]`, especially if you'll be doing file uploads.  This allows the system to control how many operations run at a time, and delay running them if there is a temporary pause in network reachability.

Comment: Thank you, that would mean a separate server request to check the validity of my token. I actually post my current token and depending on its validity I go to the success or failure block. However, I would like to just redo the whole operation upon the failure.  I cannot figure out how to do this in a smart manner. I cannot just call the very same operation (like a recursive call) now can I?

Comment: You would not need a separate request to check the validity.  If the failure block is where you go on invalid token, then put the sample code I wrote in the failure block.

Comment: You can redo the whole operation, like in my code, by copying the `AFHTTPRequestOperation` object, resetting the complete/failure blocks, and starting it again.